# #1442 - Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

MySQL triggers have a mechanism to prevent an infinite loop by refusing to perform updates to the table which may have started the trigger. However, The trigger that I have developed is free from such influences even though the safeguard against infinite loop does fire.

Error message: `#1442 - Can't update table 'ms_community_post_cpy' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Trigger:

```
 DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `CreateCommunityPost` 
AFTER INSERT ON `img_tmp` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE atlas_id INT ;
    DECLARE last_id_in_ms_community_post INT ;
    DECLARE atlas_city VARCHAR(20) ;
    DECLARE image_url VARCHAR(150) ;
    
    SET @image_url = NEW.img_url ;

select id, city into  atlas_id, atlas_city from ms_atlas order by rand() limit 1 ;

INSERT INTO `ms_community_post_cpy`(`user_id`, `content`, `cover`, `type`, `is_open`, `top`, `order`, `status`, `add_time`, `title`, `good`, `is_check`, `tag_id`, `is_vip`, `is_recommend`, `click`, `city`, `search_num`)
VALUES (atlas_id, NEW.title, null, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '', floor(0+ RAND() * 10000), 1, 60, 0, 0, floor(0+ RAND() * 10000), atlas_city, 0) ;

SET @last_id_in_ms_community_post = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO `ms_community_post_resources_cpy`(`post_id`, `resouces_url`, `type`, `add_time`)
VALUES (last_id_in_ms_community_post, image_url, 1, 0);


END

$$
DELIMITER;
```

I would like to know if there are workarounds.

Comment: in your last post you published a trigger on ms_community_post_cpy (presumably now syntactically correct) which included an insert to ms_community_post_cpy and this is where the error is coming from.

Comment: Is this part of a transaction?  Let's see the rest of the transaction.